# Where can I obtain SDK for Alfresco Community 5.2c?

Tags: eclipse, alfresco

I have Alfresco Community v5.2.0 and Alfresco Share v5.2.c that running on Apache Tomcat 7.0 Servlet/JSP Container, installed on CentOS 7.3.

To customize Alfresco I need the appropriate Alfresco SDK.

Where can I obtain it?.. I downloaded `alfresco-community-sdk-4.2.c` from sourceforge, set it up in Eclipse Luna.

Can I use this version of SDK for customize Alfresco 5.2c?

Comment: What kind of customisation are you trying to do? Did you try [the Alfresco SDK v2.2?](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/alfresco-sdk-intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using eclips for customization then follow this link to set alfresco sdk with eclips.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utYZaVe9Nd0